# Maximization problem and interpretation of the Lagrange mutipliers

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to evaluate the $\lambda$ in the result of the maximization problem of a box with a cardboard sheet of area $c$. The model is:

$$\begin{align}
\text{maximize} \quad &f(x,y,z)=xyz, \\
\text{subject to} \quad &2xy+2xz+2yz=c.
\end{align}$$

The solution is $x=y=z=\frac{\sqrt{6c}}{6}$ and $\lambda=-\frac{\sqrt{6c}}{12}$. Thus, $f(x,y,z)=(\frac{\sqrt{6c}}{6})^3=\frac{\sqrt{6}c^\frac{3}{2}}{36}$, and $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial c}=\frac{\sqrt{6c}}{24}$.

As you can see $\lambda\neq\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial c}$, but $\lambda=-2\cdot \frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial c}$.
Why is this happening if the theory states that the shadow price of a constraint is $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial c}=\lambda$?

Comment: If $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ and $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_0+\varepsilon \nabla g$, then $f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{x}_0)+ \varepsilon \lambda \| \nabla g \|$ plus higher order corrections. Similarly $g(\mathbf{x})=g(\mathbf{x}_0)+\varepsilon \| \nabla g \|$ plus higher order corrections. Thus $g$ asymptotically changed by $\varepsilon \| \nabla g \|$ and $f$ asymptotically changed by $\lambda \varepsilon \| \nabla g \|$, so the ratio is asymptotically like $\lambda$. Thus you probably made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Indeed when I get the problem started I arrive at $yz=\lambda(2y+2z),xz=\lambda(2x+2z),xy=\lambda(2x+2y)$, so summing these equations gives $2xy+2xz+2xy=c=8\lambda(x+y+z)$. If I take $x=y=z$ for granted, then $c=6x^2=24\lambda x$,so $\lambda=x/4=\sqrt{c/6}/4$.

Comment: Your denominator for $\lambda$ is incorrect. As for the sign difference, it looks like you used $f+\lambda g$ for the Lagrangian instead of $f-\lambda g$. Remember that the original equation that you’re trying to solve when using this method is $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. I understand that I made a mistake with the sign of the gradient of the constraint and now I have changed it. I need to clarify that I am using Maple to solve the system of equations: `solve({x*y-(y+x)*lambda = 0, z*x-lambda*(x+z) = 0, z*y-lambda*(y+z) = 0, 2*x*y+2*x*z+2*y*z-c = 0}, {lambda, x, y, z})`. That is the $\lambda$ it finds. Weird.

Comment: I tested it with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y*z-lambda*y-lambda*z%3D0,x*z-lambda*x-lambda*z%3D0,x*y-lambda*x-lambda*y%3D0,2*x*y%2B2*x*z%2B2*y*z%3Dc,c%3E0) as well and with both obtained the solution shown (with a positive sign for $\lambda$). Nevertheless, it is weird that both of them find the same erroneous $\lambda$.

Comment: So it's finding a minimizer with negative $x,y,z$, which also satisfies the constraint. The second answer on WA is the one you're looking for. As for the extra factor of $2$ compared to what I said, you didn't multiply the constraint by $2$ the way you did in the post.

Comment: Thanks again, @Ian. What a pitiful mistake! Shame! Shame! Shame! :'(